# Extract image dataset from tensorflow record dataset in batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I recently started studying CNNs with tensorflow and found tfrecords very helpful in speeding up the training, however I'm struggling with data API.
After parsing, my dataset is composed of (image, label) tuples, this is fine for training, however I'm trying to extract the image in another dataset to call keras.predict() on.

I've tried this solution:

```
test_set = get_set_tfrecord(test_path, _parse_function, num_parallel_calls = 4)

lab = []
f = True
for image, label in test_set.take(600):
    if f:
      img = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(image)
      f = False
    else:
      img = img.concatenate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(image))
    lab.append(label.numpy())
```

naive, not great code, but it works EXCEPT in order to perform concatenation (i.e. stacking) it loads every image into RAM.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Do you HAVE to use tfRecord? I think it makes some sense to use a tf.Dataset first and only if you are still I/O bound move on to tfRecord. Anyway, there may be a batching capability like a tf.Dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map` [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#map) from `tf.data.Dataset`. You can write the following code.

```
result = test_set.map(lambda image, label: image)
# You can iterate and check what you have received at the end.
# I expect only the images.
for image in result.take(1):
    print(image)
```

I hope that using the above code you resolve your issue and that this answer serves you well.

Comment: If the above solution worked for you, I will encourage you to upvote it so that other users could benefit from the solution.